# How Interacting with SVG Images in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, svg

After a lot of time and effort searching for the best way to interact with images in flutter I found this article on [medium article](https://jtmuller5-98869.medium.com/interacting-with-svg-images-in-flutter-f9d204ab446d#:%7E:text=Scalable%20Vector%20Graphics%20(SVGs)%20are,used%20to%20draw%20an%20image.) but I didn't understand it - I think it's complicated for a beginner like me - I followed all the instructions but the source code I get always contains many errors.
Is there anyone who has tried it or can help me convert this article into code?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [`flutter_svg`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) package. It's quite simple to use. Instead of displaying a reagular image as you would with:

```
Image.asset('path_to_img'),
```

You would use:

```
SvgPicture.asset('path_to_svg.svg')
```

---

Don't forget to add the SVG in your `pubspec.yaml` file

Answer (score -2):

Use flutter_svg package.

Documentation is at https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg.